# how to space div with content inside in html

Tags: html

how can i space my div. not to align like center/right/left

i just want to give space or a little push to the right. with content inside div

let's say like 1 meter or 2 matter just example

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<title>title</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<input type="text" name="textfield" placeholder="First name">
<input type="text" name="textfield2" placeholder="Last name">
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried a margin or padding?

Comment: @j08691 padding wasn;t good i never tried margin but i want to space inputbox with textfield then it will also space textfiled2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want to add some margin to your elements.

Try this:

```
<div style="margin-left: 20px;">
  <input type="text" name="textfield" placeholder="First name">
  <input type="text" name="textfield2" placeholder="Last name">
<div>
```

Preferably you make a .css file that contains all your styling

Comment: the problem i have. this works but it changes the layout when view on mobile only works with pc very good bt on mobile layout change